# Avoiding redundant rows in result of mysql inner join

Tags: mysql, duplicates, inner-join

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `CORPUS_FILE_SENTENCE` (
  `corpus_file_sentence_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `corpus_file_sentence_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_sentence_saved` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sentence_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `corpus_file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`corpus_file_sentence_id`),
  KEY `fk_corpus_file_sentence-corpus_file_id` (`corpus_file_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_corpus_file_sentence-corpus_file_id` FOREIGN KEY (`corpus_file_id`) REFERENCES `CORPUS_FILE` (`corpus_file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `CORPUS_FILE_PREPROCESSED_SENTENCE` (
  `corpus_file_preprocessed_sentence_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coreference_resolved_sentence_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stopword_removed_sentence_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lemmatized_sentence_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lowercased_sentence_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `preprocessed_sentence_text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_preprocessed_sentence_saved` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `corpus_file_sentence_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`corpus_file_preprocessed_sentence_id`),
  KEY `fk_corpus_file_preprocessed_sentence-corpus_file_sentence_id` (`corpus_file_sentence_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_corpus_file_preprocessed_sentence-corpus_file_sentence_id` FOREIGN KEY (`corpus_file_sentence_id`) REFERENCES `CORPUS_FILE_SENTENCE` (`corpus_file_sentence_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to show the result of Coreference Resolution along with the original sentence and I was trying

```
select 
  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_id,
  CFS.sentence_number,
  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_text,
  CFPS.coreference_resolved_sentence_text
from CORPUS_FILE_SENTENCE CFS
inner join CORPUS_FILE_PREPROCESSED_SENTENCE CFPS
  on  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_id = CFPS.corpus_file_sentence_id
  and CFS.corpus_file_id = 3;
```

This is resulting in duplicate rows of the form

[image]

How do I remove the redundant rows?

Comment: Which are the "redundant" rows & why? What does "remove" mean--& leaving what? (Remove SQL-duplicate rows via SELECT DISTINCT.) PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes version & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really strange that you get these results, but for these results you can remove the rows with nulls in the column `coreference_resolved_sentence_text` with `group by` and aggregation:

```
select 
  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_id, CFS.sentence_number, 
  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_text, max(CFPS.coreference_resolved_sentence_text) 
from CORPUS_FILE_SENTENCE CFS inner join CORPUS_FILE_PREPROCESSED_SENTENCE CFPS 
on CFS.corpus_file_sentence_id = CFPS.corpus_file_sentence_id and CFS.corpus_file_id = 3
group by 
  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_id, 
  CFS.sentence_number, 
  CFS.corpus_file_sentence_text
```